# I can't move my head on the latest update of the game

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have Minecraft Xbox 360 Edition on the latest update, but I have a problem. I can't seem to move my head in any direction. I have tried to clear my cache and even tried reinstalling the latest update, but I still have the problem. Is there a solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed a bug in the software. It will randomly reset various settings (not always the same onces). The bug has been there since the Xbox Edition was first released and 4J have tried to fix it in the past... obviously without success. I remember that, a long time ago, 4JSteve indicated the bug had something to do with the analog controllers... but I'm getting up there and my memory can be pretty sketch these days... so don't hold me to that, OK. The bug can hit at any time, but usually hits more people after an update. Fortunately, the fix is pretty simple once you're aware of what to do about it.

Help & Options > Settings > Reset to Defaults

This should clear the condition... then individually reset any parameters you want different from the defaults.

Comment: No problem! :) have fun!

Comment: @SofiaSara if you accept this answer, please click on the gray check on the left of the answers next to the votes. It will turn green, and it will mean that the answer is accepted.